# django server not running on host with vagrant

Tags: django, vagrant, virtualbox, portforwarding

Vagrantfile:

```
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8080, host: 8080
```

On my virtual machine I am running this command:

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080
```

But when I try to `curl` on host machine, response is `curl: (52) Empty reply from server` and on browser it says `127.0.0.1 didn’t send any data.`

I looked on stackoverflow for this problem, most of them were able to resolve it by adding `0.0.0.0` to the `runserver` command. But, I have already added it.

I tried:

1. `Disabling the firewall` and allowing all connections to the virtual machine by `accepting all input and output in iptables.`
2. I changed the `127.0.0.1 localhost` in /etc/hosts to `0.0.0.0 localhost` but still the same response.
3. I ensured that my host machine is not preventing it by disabling the firewall on my host machine too.

Note: I am using ubuntu machine on virtual box and mac OS on host.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While the virtual machine is running, any changes to the Vagrantfile are not properly registered by the machine even if you run `vagrant up`.

To ensure that all the changes get reflected correctly, the virtual machine should be halted and then run again.

In my case, I had changed the forwarding ports while the vagrant was running. I was doing `vagrant up` assuming the changes will get reflected but they did not. 
Doing `vagrant halt` followed by `vagrant up` solved my issue.

Comment: you can simply run `vagrant reload` after changes on the Vagrantfile

Comment: @FrédéricHenri I didn't know that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your port forwards are not auto corrected. If so, halt all the machines and remove the port forwarding cache by following:

```
rm -rf ~/.vagrant.d/data/fp-leases
```